# Cross-domain scripting using jQuery.support.cors = true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I've been working on various samples showing off cross-domain scripting and ran into a case where I wanted to use jQuery.support.cors = true along with an Ajax call to retrieve data from a webservice.  I have an example of the webservice working [using jsonp](http://jsfiddle.net/shelbyz/jdNUn/) that I thought would be simple to add jQuery.support.cors = true, change the dataType to "json", and remove the &$callback=? from the url.  I can see the response coming back from the webservice (Netflix) with the expected data, but when the ajax call returns it executes the error functions as opposed to success.

I originally thought that maybe the webservice did not have the proper cors headers, but I would tend to think a formatted response received would equate to the header existing.  Perhaps I'm not formatting the success/error function properly and the Ajax result does not like that.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shelbyz/Tg4eZ/) where it is attempting to use jQuery.support.cors to no avail.

Comment: "I would tend to think a formatted response received would equate to the header existing" — It doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: `curl -i  "http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Titles?$select=Name,Runtime,ReleaseYear&$filter=dark&$orderby=Name&$format=json"`

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 3386076
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 01 May 2012 14:37:06 GMT
Vary: *
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
DataServiceVersion: 2.0;
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 14:36:37 GMT
```

There is no CORS related header. Netflix do not permit CORS requests.

Comment: I guess II'm not certain why I can still see the resulting data payload if they don't support cors.  Shouldn't the query be blocked in total?

Comment: @ShelbyZ — No. Just not visible to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Surely in this example, Netflix would be blocking anything originating outside their own servers.